# Separating array with different objects into specific object arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

Imagine I have an array with different types of objects such as:

```
[1,true,'hello',true,2,' ','world']
```

I'm trying to create a function that outputs an array of arrays with those objects separated.

```
[ [1,2] , ['hello', ' ', 'world'] , [true,true] ]
```

So far i've come with this:

```
def same_object arg
    arg.inject([]){ |acc,value| 
            flag = 0
            acc.each do |i|
                if i[0] != nil && value.class == i[0].class
                    i << value
                    flag = 1
                end
            end

            if flag == 0
                acc << [value]
            end
    }
end
```

The problem is that apparently I get an error when I do:

```
value.class == i[0].class
```

Which is kind of weird, because for me it makes sense. I'm new to ruby and I'd appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example fails, because you do not return updated `acc` at the end of the `inject` block. Just add `acc` before the closing `}`:

```
  #...
  end
  acc
}
```

Beside that I would do something like this:

```
[1,true,'hello',true,2,' ','world'].group_by(&:class).values
#=> [[1, 2], [true, true], ["hello", " ", "world"]]
```

Comment: Do you have any clue why this goes wrong inside mine? Your answer is pretty awesome anyways : )

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
from singlefile.rb:48:in `block in same_object'
from singlefile.rb:46:in `each'
from singlefile.rb:46:in `inject'
from singlefile.rb:46:in `same_object'

Comment: what I think is weird is that i'm checking for the nil class, so it shouldn't fail :/

Comment: @ManoelRibeiro You need to have `acc` returned as the last line of your block.  Without this,  it will return `nil` to the next cycle of `inject` in the case that `flag != 0`.

Comment: @PinnyM, why would this happen?

Comment: Because that's how `inject` works :)  The accumulator/memo object (`acc` for your case) starts off as `nil` or as the passed in object (`[]` in your case) and for each consecutive pass it is the result returned by the block on the previous pass.  This method is commonly called `reduce` in other languages (also aliased as such in ruby).  Have a look at the `Enumerable#each_with_object` method that may be more in line with what you are expecting.